# print(args.task[0]) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
def get_opts():
    model_names = sorted(
        name
        for name in models.__dict__
        if name.islower()
        and not name.startswith("__")
        and callable(models.__dict__[name])
    )

    # general setting
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="ACPL")
    parser.add_argument("--task", choices=["cx14", "cxp", "isic"], nargs="*", type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args(args=[])
    return args

args = get_opts()
print(args.task[0])
```

### The following is the error message displayed:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5fd1fb76e64f> in <module>()
      1 args = get_opts()
----> 2 print(args.task[0])

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What did I do wrong? Why the type of "args.task" is "None"? Why not a "list"？

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [mre]. How did you run the program, in order to cause the problem? It's relevant here because the problem is specifically about parsing the command line. I am guessing that you tried calling it without any `--task`s specified, and expected an empty list. Unfortunately, `nargs='*'` doesn't work this way - it treats zero as a special case. You need to specify a `default` explicitly.

Comment: I can't find a linked duplicate for that, and the documentation doesn't seem to explain it clearly; so if I understand the problem correctly I'll be happy to turn that into an answer.